# WSO2 Multiple scopes for a single API possible

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can we give multiple scopes for a single API itself?

Comment: why are you asking the same question again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480455/adding-scopes-programatically-in-wso2-apim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding scopes programatically in wso2 APIM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480455/adding-scopes-programatically-in-wso2-apim)

Comment: I was more focused on giving multiple scopes for the same API.
Since in the publisher UI , it allows to select only one scope for an API.
Is it possible /good way to associate multiple scopes for a single API?

Comment: Any answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scopes are attached to REST resources. You can have only one scope for each REST resource.